# Will two devices connected to the same wifi, talk via the access point for communicating with each other?

Tags: wifi

If two devices A and B are connected to same wifi via access point C, and if A pings B, will those packets be directly picked up by B or will they be captured by C and then retransmitted such that B can capture them?

Using wireshark to capture packets shows that mac addresses in the ping packets are of A and B [not sure if C is even supposed to have one], thus if the packets are going via C, then C is analogus to a hub.

A link to a primer on 802.11[?] that covers this aspect would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

In a standard (i.e. non-AdHoc) WiFi network the answer is yes, packets sent between WiFi Stations will go via the Access Point. As allen-smithee mentions, the analogy probably makes more sense if you think of the AP as a switch, with the "association" between each station being a cable.

A good way to test this would be to see if two clients A & B, which are connected to an access point C but are a long way apart so they cannot hear each other, can sent packets to each other.

NB: If the client A & B are close enough to hear each other, it would be possible for them to communicate directly, but implementing the communications like this would introduce a lot of complexities.

A great primer on WiFi is Matthew Gast's book  [802.11 Wireless Networks: The Definitive Guide](http://www.itc.edu.kh/bib/ebook/storage/802.11%20Wireless%20Networks%20The%20Definitive%20Guide.pdf) (see the link for a "copy"). In particular Chapter 4. Also, table 4-2 summarises the 4 address fields and what "address" will be present in them for the different functions in WiFi.

Answer (score 8):

An 802.11 frame can have up to 4 MAC addresses - sender, destination and the MACs of the transmitting and receiving radio points (the AP). If you're only seeing the sender and destination then likely you are seeing a ['fake Ethernet capture'](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Wi-Fi#A802.11_vs._.22fake_Ethernet.22_captures).

'Hub' probably isn't really the right term to describe an AP any more. A wireless network is basically a single medium, like a hub network, with bandwidth shared between clients. However [MIMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO) increases the bandwidth by effectively layering a greater number of media. A switched ethernet network is really just a medium per client (one wire to each client from the switch) so if a MIMO wireless network had enough layers and the AP had more bandwidth than any one client it would resemble a switched network in some ways.

For a general description of 802.11 and the frames see [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757419(v=ws.10).aspx).
For an interesting look at MAC address usage in 802.11 see [this link](http://mrncciew.com/2014/09/28/cwap-mac-headeraddresses/).

The amount of work that the AP does for retransmitting packets from A to B is an interesting question. I believe that most APs will inspect the packets at the data layer and then construct a new packet for transmission to the other client. The most important reason for this is to provide some degree of inter-client protection. Another thing to consider is if the AP has WPA/WPA2 Enterprise security where per-client encryption is used so the AP has to decrypt and re-encrypt the packets.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and links, especially the wireshark part (I again realized that partial knowledge can be dangerous).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **YES**. In your scenario (non AdHOC connection) both devices must be connected via an Access Point. WiFi is a physical layer that converts data (0s and 1s) into radio signals. So **physically** the packets must **pass through** the access point **otherwise there can not be communication** with any other device.

The reason you can't see any information on your Wireshark, I assume, is because you are looking at **Layer 3** (*IP Addresses*) which doesn't change. If you take a closer look at **Layer 2** (*link layer*) which **changes at every hop** you will find the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of the last hop, in this case of your router.

NOTE: That is what normally happens to every network with a router. There is a technique called *transparent routing* which conceals the presence of a host, usually for security reasons (e.g. firewalls are usually performing transparent routing).

Here is some further reading:

1. [What happens, when router receives packet?](https://supportforums.cisco.com/blog/153276/what-happens-when-router-receives-packet) - CISCO Forums
2. http://www.cs.miami.edu/~burt/learning/Csc524.092/notes/ip_example.html  - Miami University CS Class Notes